# Flutter code not compiling after upgrade to version 1.27.0-8.0.pre

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, upgrade, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to run my desktop flutter application. Since i've upgraded my flutter version to dev channel (flutter version 1.27.0-8.0.pre), code is not compiling after that. It shows following error on code compilation.

[image]

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: did you try running 'flutter clean' ?

Comment: Can you paste the card code where it shows error and also plugins as I'm seeing ansestortype is not accessible by context, there are some migrations going on in flutter so... To solve this post code